# Javascript - How to merge to objects but keep only the same properties

Tags: javascript

I search a lots but what I got is how to merge objects and keeps properties of both. How about keep only the same props only? For example:

```
const obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
const obj2 = {a: 3, b:3, d:5, e:7}
```

Is there any way to create an obj3 which is {a:3, b:3} (only keep props in both objects)?

Comment: Either create your own algorithm or use a library like lodash

Comment: should it show the matching properties and the values ​​of object 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to `reduce` by `obj2`'s entries, assigning them to the accumulator object if the property exists in `obj1`:

```js
const obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
const obj2 = {a: 3, b:3, d:5, e:7}

console.log(
  Object.entries(obj2).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
    if (key in obj1) a[key] = val;
    return a;
  }, {})
);
```

Comment: Not gonna get much better than that

Comment: That's nice. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer is a good way to go but the following might turn out to be more efficient;

```js
var obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3},
    obj2 = {a: 3, b:3, d:5, e:7},
    res  = {};
for (k in obj1) k in obj2 && (res[k] = obj2[k]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert to an array (with the help of `Object.entries`) to filter – then convert back (with the help of `reduce`)

```
Object.entries(obj2)
    .filter(([key]) => (key in obj1))
    .reduce((obj, [key, val]) => ({...obj, [key]: val}), {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that tries to improve efficiency by looping over the object with fewer keys (less iterations):

```js
const obj1 = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
const obj2 = {a: 3, b:3, d:5, e:7}

// find sm/lg object by key length
let [sm,lg]=[obj1,obj2].sort((a,b)=>(
  Object.keys(a).length-Object.keys(b).length
));

const merged = {}

// make small object outer loop 
for (let key in sm){
  if (key in lg)
    merged[key]=obj2[key] // only store if key in both objects
}

console.log(merged);
```